# What is equivalent to conatiner name in docker-composer to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have project which uses `nginx` and `php-fpm` container.

In `docker-compose`, I can use this nginx setting `fastcgi_pass php:9000;`
(`php` is container name of `php-fpm`)

in nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xxx.example.com;
  index  index.php index.html index.htm;
  root /var/www/public;
  client_max_body_size 200M; # 413 Request Entity Too Large
  location / {
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass 0.0.0.0:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_index index.php;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
 }
```

However now I want to use set(`nginx`, `php-fpm` in `ECS`.

In `Ecs` there is not container name.

And `php-fpm` container accept only

netstat -an|grep LISTEN

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Now, I tried few patterns in `nginx.conf`

```
   fastcgi_pass php:9000;
   #fastcgi_pass 0.0.0.0:9000;
   #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
   #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

but either one doesn't work.

How can I set?

Comment: Docker converts container names to DNS records, `php:9000` is no different to specifying an IPv4:port. What is the address of the server exposing your `php-fpm` service? If they're networked, you can add your own DNS file or just specify its IPv4. If they're not networked, you will not be able to contact the service. Looking at your netstat output, you only have it exposed to Ipv6.

Comment: ECS docker-compose uses AWS CloudMap to map the container names so that they should still work in the AWS environment. Are you seeing errors to the contrary?

Comment: @Jaquarh  default `fpm-fpm` image doesn't have IPv4 port as `netstat -an|grep LISTEN` shows. it is default behavior but in `docker compose` I can access without ipv4 setting.

Comment: @MarkB I meant that I use `ECS` not `docker-compose` in local environment I can assure the container works in `docker-compose` and now I want to set ECS containers. ECS and docker-compose are very alike but, connection between containers are defferent.

Comment: Well ECS does have container names like docker-compose, via integration with AWS CloudMap. However if both containers are running within the same Fargate task, then they can also access each other via `127.0.0.1` on their respective ports.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for your comment, yes normally I can access with `127.0.0.1:9000`.  However in this case , `php-fpm` opens only ipv6 port  like this `tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN` or `fastcgi protocol` Is there any way to access ipv6 port between container??

Comment: I don't see any documentation on IPv6 between containers in Fargate. You could try `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` which is the IPv6 equivalent of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thank you I have tried `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000` but in vain.  However your advice gives me the progress. I think I should change the default behavior of php-fpm to accept `127.0.0.1:9000`